# Which chip to use for automation using Wifi?

Tags: embedded, wifi, automation

I am working on a project where I will be controlling a device using android mobile phone (WiFi as medium). Which is the chip at present in the market which is low cost and effective for my application. the size is of no concern (it can be big).

Comment: What are you looking at already? What solutions do you feel may be appropriate? Without a hint of any other information this question is really hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently evaluating the [CC3000 from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3000). It comes at a rather low price, can be used via its SPI interface and a few demo boards are available as well. My current platform is the Atmel AVR32 architecture.